# Query SharePoint Online Term Store via REST

Tags: java, rest, sharepoint, soap

I would like to query and retrieve terms from a termset in my SharePoint Online term store, so they can be used as lookup data from the UI in an external web application (JAVA backend, angular/material frontend).

This is NOT a Provider Hosted SharePoint App, so I need to access the term store using REST or SOAP via the web.

What I am trying to build is something similar to the Taxonomy Picker component created by the MSFT OfficeDev PnP team (https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/dev/Components/Core.TaxonomyPicker), except that it should not be dependent on being run within a Provider-Hosted SharePoint app.

Is this possible?  Is there such an API that can be leveraged, with security, etc., so we can pass in a client secret key or something and call the REST/SOAP api to retrieve terms?

I don't need to update terms, only retrieve them (label and termID).

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no REST api for taxonomy service:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/418be97e-1fb0-4c04-922f-e90c78476720/rest-apis-for-taxonomy-in-2013?forum=appsforsharepoint

You can check this fact by yourself using ilspy/reflector to look at class attributes from server object model it has `ClientLibraryTargets = ClientLibraryTargets.NonRESTful` like that:

```
namespace Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy
{
    [ClientCallableType(ServerTypeId = "A99E4A8F-010B-4e56-9B29-B7BD6EC51263", ClientLibraryTargets = ClientLibraryTargets.NonRESTful)]
    // ....
    public abstract class TermSetItem : TaxonomyItem
```

Comment: This is no longer true: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-managed-metadata-services-rest-api

Answer (score 0):

Probably not be exactly what you need, but this one will REST return used terms...
With some *workarounds*, you can get all the terms returned...

https://site/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TaxonomyHiddenList')/items

https://site/Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList/

Comment: It is always empty

Answer (score 0):

you can use the SOAP webservice /_vti_bin/taxonomyclientservice.asmx to query the termstore

Answer (score 0):

As of the 2.1 REST API (possibly earlier), this can be done.

See this answer:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/283332/taxonomyclientservice-is-still-the-way-to-go/287868#287868 or [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-managed-metadata-services-rest-api) that answer is based on.

Edit: To avoid this being a link-only answer, I have replicated the examples below.

**TermStore groups:**

To list:

```
Endpoint : https://testinglala.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.1/termStore/groups  
Method : GET  
Headers : {"Content-Type": "application/json",
           "Authorization": "Bearer <Bearer Token>"}
```

To create:

```
 Endpoint : https://testinglala.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.1/termStore/groups    
 Method : POST    
 Headers : {"Content-Type": "application/json",  
            "Authorization": "Bearer <Bearer Token>"}
 Body : {"name":"FromRESTAPI", "description":"Description For FromRESTAPI"}
```

**Term Sets:**

To List:

```
Endpoint : https://testinglala.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.1/termStore/groups/122d92ab-    d7a8-479f-9888-8d4421f8218f/sets
Method : GET    
Headers : {"Content-Type": "application/json",  
           "Authorization": "Bearer <Bearer Token>"}
```

To Create:

```
Endpoint : https://testinglala.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.1/termStore/groups/122d92ab-d7a8-479f-9888-8d4421f8218f/sets      
Method : POST      
Headers : {"Content-Type": "application/json",    
           "Authorization": "Bearer <Bearer Token>"}
Body : {"description": "","localizedNames": [{"name": "OperationLevel","languageTag": "en-US"}]}
```

To Update:

```
Endpoint : https://testinglala.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.1/termStore/groups/122d92ab-d7a8-479f-9888-8d4421f8218f/sets/dbc06a0b-7f38-42dc-84a7-0b734f350303          
Method : PATCH         
Headers : {"Content-Type": "application/json",        
           "Authorization": "Bearer <Bearer Token>"}    
Body : {"description": "Added description","localizedNames": [{"name": "OperationLevelUpdated","languageTag": "en-US"}]}
```

To Delete:

```
Endpoint : https://testinglala.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.1/termStore/groups/122d92ab-d7a8-479f-9888-8d4421f8218f/sets/dbc06a0b-7f38-42dc-84a7-0b734f350303            
Method : DELETE          
Headers : {"Content-Type": "application/json",          
           "Authorization": "Bearer <Bearer Token>"}
```

**Terms**

To List:

```
Endpoint : https://testinglala.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.1/termStore/groups/122d92ab-d7a8-479f-9888-8d4421f8218f/sets/8ed8c9ea-7052-4c1d-a4d7-b9c10bffea6f/terms      
Method : GET      
Headers : {"Content-Type": "application/json",    
           "Authorization": "Bearer <Bearer Token>"}
```

To Create (note, isDefault must be true or it will fail):

```
Endpoint : https://testinglala.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.1/termStore/groups/122d92ab-d7a8-479f-9888-8d4421f8218f/sets/8ed8c9ea-7052-4c1d-a4d7-b9c10bffea6f/children        
Method : POST        
Headers : {"Content-Type": "application/json",      
           "Authorization": "Bearer <Bearer Token>"}   
Body : {"labels": [{"name": "AI","isDefault":true,"languageTag": "en-US"}],"descriptions": [{"description": "AI Innovation","languageTag": "en-US"}]}
```

To Update (I haven't used this):

```
Endpoint : https://testinglala.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.1/termStore/groups/122d92ab-d7a8-479f-9888-8d4421f8218f/sets/8ed8c9ea-7052-4c1d-a4d7-b9c10bffea6f/terms/b8b3e828-cdf7-46b2-889e-f5f797a05aa3          
Method : PATCH          
Headers : {"Content-Type": "application/json",        
          "Authorization": "Bearer <Bearer Token>"}     
Body : {"labels": [{"name": "AI Updated","isDefault":true,"languageTag": "en-US"}],"descriptions": [{"description": "AI Innovation Updated","languageTag": "en-US"}]}
```

To Delete:

```
Endpoint : https://testinglala.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.1/termStore/groups/122d92ab-d7a8-479f-9888-8d4421f8218f/sets/8ed8c9ea-7052-4c1d-a4d7-b9c10bffea6f/terms/b8b3e828-cdf7-46b2-889e-f5f797a05aa3            
Method : DELETE            
Headers : {"Content-Type": "application/json",          
           "Authorization": "Bearer <Bearer Token>"}
```

**Nested Terms** (my minor contribution)

To List:

```
Endpoint : https://testinglala.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.1/termStore/groups/122d92ab-d7a8-479f-9888-8d4421f8218f/sets/8ed8c9ea-7052-4c1d-a4d7-b9c10bffea6f/terms/12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012/children      
Method : GET      
Headers : {"Content-Type": "application/json",    
           "Authorization": "Bearer <Bearer Token>"}
```

I haven't yet created, updated, or deleted a nested term. I'll update this answer if I do.